# Minimising number of dynamic pages to map scattered points using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, algorithm, data-driven-pages, maximum-coverage-problem

From time to time I have to produce mapbook to show points of interest. First step to create pages, using regular mesh:

[image]

I don't like the solution because a) there are some pages with single points (e.g. page 25) sitting on the edge and b) too many pages.

First issue is easy to fix using code, - move rectangle of page extent to center of relevant points extent:

[image]

I still don't like it, it looks very crowded because number of pages remains the same. 
Remember, they all end up being actual A3 paper pages in multiple copies of report !.

So I've cooked a code that reduce number of pages. In this example from 45 to 34.

[image]

I am not sure if this the best result that can be achieved,

What is the best strategy (pseudo code, publication, Python library) to shuffle through points in order to minimise number of given size rectangles to capture all of the points?
Surely, someone discovered it in game theory, military art or fishing industry

**This is update to original question:**

This shows real extent and page size required:

[image]

Closer zoom showing 10 out of 164 pages:

[image]

[Sample Point Feature Class](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6B33FrGNitPV1RHVWlQaEMtQ0E/view?usp=sharing)

Rectangle size can change as soon as it stays within the limits, i.e. smaller is fine.

Comment: In my opinion the regular mesh is the best option. Map readers are expecting something like that because they are used to it. The other options are crowded and, in my opinion, confusing. There are certainly optimising algorithms that will do what you want, but I don't think your audience will appreciate them. +1 though because I appreciate what you are trying to do. Finally, one way to reduce the number of pages is to change the scale.

Comment: I mostly agree with Fezter. There are cases where a non-continuous map book has its place and I'll be interested to see answers (even your current code if you want to share). For example a book of trails where you want each trail on its own map and don't care about showing the others (though you might still want a smaller scale single map showing them all in relative position). Just looking at your example images I think in this case you *would* want a continuous coverage between pages, even if it means extras, unless the points have an inherent grouping property.

Comment: @Fezter, regular mesh works when page size is comparable to total extent, both this and scale change aren't the case here

Comment: @ChrisW, have a look at updated question. It is exactly about grouping, but how? I had a spare hour at home and coded it using Avenue. Shall I post a pseudo code?

Comment: Would **[Grouping Analysis](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005p00000051000000)** help here?

Comment: No. Because spatial Constraints does nothing unless there is a 'similarity value' stored in numeric field, what @ChrisW calls inherent grouping property

Comment: I can see what you're trying to achieve but wouldn't fancy doing this in arcpy... it looks like something I'd have a crack at in C# with ArcObjects; something like centre of features if you can get more than one on a page otherwise centre page on feature, trying to avoid overprinting already allocated features. I say trying to place a regular grid is not the best option as the locations are too sparse for regularity.. perhaps though a hybrid solution of a regular grid for the dense areas and ungridded extents for sparse areas.

Comment: Afraid I can't offer anything further. Like you say, my first thought was a grouping/cluster analysis, but as you further mention there's no value to use. Much like people often want to set a max number of items to a group. I'm nowhere near familiar enough with grouping or even code and algorithms yet to tackle this kind of problem. Your revised image definitely better illustrates the issue (because those are far more sparse than the initial ones), but if those are your scale/pagesize constraints I'm not sure what more you could do - they already look pretty minimal.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson,  what I've done using Avenue is doable in Python. Used former because in  geometry games former is still superior. Pick point, find nearest manhattan distance neighbour, create multipoint, get extent. Quit if over extent. Removed grouped from original list, proceed with remaining. I thought the  sorting order important, tried to change. Very little difference...

Comment: Yes it's doable in python with significant effort. When dealing with geometries I prefer ArcObjects in C#. As Chris said they already look fairly minimal why not stick with what you've got and call it done.

Comment: @FlexiIP, Can rectangle size differ one from another?

Comment: Can you share your point dataset to see how effective is my algorithm? Then I will share the results

Comment: @FaridCher Try this https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6B33FrGNitPV1RHVWlQaEMtQ0E/view?usp=sharing  They are points shown on my solution below, I don't think number of pages reducable in this case. Let me know if you'd like ones from OP

Comment: Oops, missed your first comment. Size can change as soon as it stays within the limits, i.e. smaller is fine

Comment: @FelixIP, yes please share the original dataset in your question. I find this a very interesting question. In fact I consider your questions to be very fundamental

Comment: Can do it Monday sorry

Comment: @FaridCher    Uploaded https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6B33FrGNitPckFZNlFvYzV1SDQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @FaridCher have a look at updated answer below, it looks like some strategy is better than nothing

Comment: @FelixIP sorry I totally forgot. I posted my answer however I am so busy with my phd proposal these days so please consider implementing the algorithm and see the number of rectangles it creates.

Answer (score 7):

This is not the answer, I just thought I post Python solution for those who interested:

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# PAGE MAKER
# 
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy, traceback, os, sys
from arcpy import env

width=650
height=500

try:
    def showPyMessage():
            arcpy.AddMessage(str(time.ctime()) + " - " + message)
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    points = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"points")[0]
    pgons = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"pages")[0]

    g=arcpy.Geometry()
    geometryList=arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(points,g)
    geometryList=[p.firstPoint for p in geometryList]
    curT = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(pgons,"SHAPE@")
    while True:
        nPoints=len(geometryList)
        small=[geometryList.pop(0)]
        for p in geometryList:
            small.append(p)
            mPoint=arcpy.Multipoint(arcpy.Array(small))
            ext=mPoint.extent
            cHeight=ext.height
            cWidth=ext.width
            if cHeight>height or cWidth>width:
                small.remove(p)
        mPoint=arcpy.Multipoint(arcpy.Array(small))
        ext=mPoint.extent
        xC=(ext.XMin+ext.XMax)/2
        yC=(ext.YMin+ext.YMax)/2
        LL=arcpy.Point (xC-width/2,yC-height/2)
        UL=arcpy.Point (xC-width/2,yC+height/2)
        UR=arcpy.Point (xC+width/2,yC+height/2)
        LR=arcpy.Point (xC+width/2,yC-height/2)
        pgon=arcpy.Polygon(arcpy.Array([LL,UL,UR,LR]))
        curT.insertRow((pgon,))
        short=filter(lambda x: x not in small,geometryList)
        arcpy.AddMessage('Grabbed %i points, %i to go' %(len(small),len(short)))
        if len(short)==0: break
        geometryList=short[:]
    del mxd
except:
    message = "\n*** PYTHON ERRORS *** "; showPyMessage()
    message = "Python Traceback Info: " + traceback.format_tb(sys.exc_info()[2])[0]; showPyMessage()
    message = "Python Error Info: " +  str(sys.exc_type)+ ": " + str(sys.exc_value) + "\n"; showPyMessage()
```

applied it lately for survey planning:

[image]

UPDATE:

It seems that for some patterns dealing with ‘stray’ points first is the way to go.
I’ve used ‘convex hull’ peel to identify them, idea of whuber, can’t find post, sorry.

[image]

Comment: Is this the post by @whuber that you were looking for?  http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/161855/115

Comment: Yes it is. I used to to sort points before "hunt" start. I'll update my own answer tomorrow. Not easy without desktop

Answer (score 4):

This looks like the geometric version of the [Maximum Coverage Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_coverage_problem) which is closely related to the [Set Cover Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem), and those two are NP-Complete.

So to solve it, one could use approximation. I would try the following algorithm and it seems to work perfectly. Although due to the complexity of problem, we cannot find the best answer.

1. Foreach point generate N=10 rectangles in random distances; just to make sure the rectangle covers the point (each rectangle has at least one point belongs to it and each point belongs to at least one rectangle)
2. Repeat until all points are covered:
   get rectangle covering max number of uncovered points. Mark points as covered.

an implementation of this algorithm, only for circle, is here: http://jsfiddle.net/nwvao72r/3/

Comment: You may be interested in http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/227344/115 if you have not seen it.