# Create fishnet only where cells overlay point feature using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, point, vector-grid

Is there a way to create a fishnet where cells are only generated where they would overlap a point feature in ArcMap 10.3?

Comment: can you create fishnet for the entire area, delete cells that do not overlap the Points?

Comment: There are many avenues in ArcGIS, e.g. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154975/how-to-minimise-number-of-dynamic-pages-to-map-scattered-point

Comment: I would also create fishnet, use spatial selection to find and delete empty boxes... Create model with modelbuilder if you are doing this frequently

Comment: @klewis you should write that up as an answer, I think it's the best option

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to create a Fishnet and delete the Cells that do not overlap a Point. Select_by_Location is the tool to Select Cells that Intersect Points. Open the Attribute Table, switch the selection, Delete.

Comment: This does indeed work. My original intention was to try and reduce the processing time as it was a very fine fishnet and I only actually needed several hundred out of the million odd cells produced.