# Pratical Grid Index for Data Driven Pages

Tags: arcpy, data-driven-pages

I'm trying to automatically generate a smart grid index for data driven pages, though frustratingly, the grid index created by the Grid Index Features tool, seems to start the grid at the bottom left corner (see below)[image]

And isn't mart enough to move re-position itself to remove redundant grids, ideally, if it were intuitive it would shift and thus could remove grid one from the equation.

[image]

Has anyone come into this issue? Or found a workaround to create a nice grid index? Would love to get your insight to this problem.

Comment: Why it should start at the upper row?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. When the grid index tool is run, it created the grid as shown above.

Comment: I am talking about your first sentence, expressing frustration that grids starts at lower left corner. So, again, why it should start somewhere else?

Comment: Well my concern was that it starts right on the bottom left corner, Ideally you would like to center the dataframe so that its not all in the corner. Whether it was the top left or top right corner, the end goal is to place it logically near the middle

Comment: This is not that simple https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154975/minimising-number-of-dynamic-pages-to-map-scattered-points-using-arcgis-desktop